# A tag for designing digital circuits

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently when someone asks a question about implementing an algorithm in hardware, such as [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/20771/230), or about a vhdl or verilog problem we do not seem to have a succinct tag for such a domain.

We have [digital-logic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-logic), and if the question specifies a language, we have both [vhdl](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vhdl) and [verilog](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verilog).

Is there a tag that would encompass this domain better then [digital-logic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-logic)?

Comment: I got a downvote, does that mean someone wants to just keep [tag:digital-logic]. I thought of [tag:vlsi] but it seemed wrong for this, since we are not going transistor level.

Comment: Yes, just keep digital-logic.

Comment: @BrianCarlton, I assumed there was a better thing to call it, but in retrospect, this makes sense. I will accept my answer and move forward.

Answer (score 5):

[digital-logic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-logic) is the best choice, we should keep it.

Comment: answer to vote on. It seems people prefer just keeping the current tag.

Comment: I can't think of much else to call it... A lot of digital questions aren't related to any HDL

Comment: @W5VO, I thought I may not know enough and that there was a term those in the field may prefer. Question answered.